# Adding many double type arguments into List java

Tags: java, list, arraylist

Edit: Thanx, my trouble has been solved.

I'm lookin for anwser for my trouble. In my exercise I have to create class "MyVector" (from the beggining, I can't use "Vector" class) which takes many arguments - double types. Next, I have to do an operation (for example multiplication of each element). How to change this code so that an object of this class has any number of type arguments?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class Wektor<T> {

    private List<T> myWektor;

    public Wektor(T... argSet){
        this.myWektor = Arrays.asList(argSet);
        printWek();
    }

    public void printWek() {
        for (T wek : myWektor) {
            System.out.println(wek);
        }
    }
}
```

for example

```
MyVector wek = new MyVector(5.5, 3, 2.2, 1, 7.5);
```

Comment: Do you know about generics in Java? See https://www.baeldung.com/java-generics

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question. Do you want the vector to take any type besides double?

Comment: And why are you using a List of double arrays?

Answer (score 0):

You can use generics for this:

```
public class MyVector<T> {

    public List<T> myWektor;

    public MyVector(T... argSet){
        this.myWektor = Arrays.asList(argSet);

    }
}
```

Then initialize it with doubles or whatever you want.

```
MyVector<Double> foo = new MyVector<Double>(11.1, 12.1, 45.0);
MyVector<String> bar = new MyVector<String>("baz", "yo");
```

Answer (score 0):

List is a type which takes a generic argument which you can explain as a type reference. A primitive type is no type reference, so you can't pass it as one. In java primitve types are written in lowercase, like `double`, `int` and so on. But each primitive has a seperate implementation, they're written in Uppercase, so just pass `Double` instead of the primitive one.

```java
public class MyVector {

        public List<Double> myWektor;

        public MyVector(Double... argSet){
            this.myWektor = Arrays.asList(argSet);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a class assignment.  The goal here may be to understand how a dynamically built `List` is implemented rather than trying to wrap one inside your own class.

Assuming..

- 'don't use `Vector`' really means 'don't use Java Collections`
- your custom collection will only accept primitive doubles
- you have implemented (or are implementing) an `add(double)` method

Consider the following:

```
public MyVector(double... values) {
  this(); // assuming you have a default constructor that does generic setup stuff
  for (double value : values) {
    add(value);
  }
}
```

Note that `Arrays.asList..` produces an fixed-size `List` backed by the array from which it is created.  This means you can never alter the incrase/decrease the size of your `MyVector` so you may as well just use an array.  You will need to build a new `List` every time you add/remove elements - in which case you may as well use an array internally.  It also means that the array that the JRE creates for your arguments won't go away until you clean up your instance of `MyVector` because it is retained to back the resulting `List`.